# Python Command Line Error

Tags: python, command-line, command

So I haven't used python for a while, so I decided to try going back to it. I had some files that I had made, so I tried activating it on Command Prompt. But when I tried to open it, it just said:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

And it just ignores my command.

I don't see anything wrong with my code. It's pretty simple. It's just:

```
print("Enter a number: ")
number1 = int(raw_input())
print("Enter another number: ")
number2 = int(raw_input())
print("The sum is: " + str(number1+number2))
```

And I do believe it is in the right folder, so do I have to reinstall it?

Does anybody know what to do? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seeing as you're on Windows, type python <insertfilenamehere>.py into the command prompt to run the program.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to type the "python" before it.